# Azure Devops enconding issues between agent pool and the final agent

Tags: azure-devops

I have a strange symptom that seems to be the agent changing the encoding of a file when the transfer from the pool agent to the deployment agent. The issue is that special chars on files (after they are copied to the deployment agent) are missing. For example "é" is "Ã‰" on the final stage.

After some debugging I was able to find that the encoding is still fine on the Pool Agent.

Anyone have any idea of how can I fix this issue?

Comment: This problem might be caused by the incorrect default character encoding of the application installed in the deployment agent machine. You can try changing the default character encoding of the application which opens the files. Please refer to this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/239810/setting-utf8-as-default-character-encoding-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that special chars on files (after they are copied to the
>   deployment agent) are missing.

Check if the encoding way of files is same before and after deployment.

As I know it's recommended to use UTF-8. So if your original files are using windows1251 or other encoding ways, devops may change it to UTF-8 and causes this issue. Sorry for the negative answer but it's by design, see similar issues [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/285520/view.html).